# How to use wildcard segment with nested resource in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, wildcard

I find my routes skills are still lacking. Apologies in advance if this is a numbskull question.

I'm building an API-accessible application. In this application, I have these classes: `Person`, `Organization`, `Program`, and `Relationship`. `Relationship` can be tagged with `admin` so that I can do something like `@person.administrated_organizations` (the details of how I do this aren't that pertinent to this question).

In my API application, I have a controller called `AdministratedThingsController`.

Currently, in `routes.rb`, I do something like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do     

  namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    namespace :v0 do
      resources :people do
        get    'administrated/*things_type',     to: 'administrated_things#index'
        post   'administrated/*things_type',     to: 'administrated_things#create'
        get    'administrated/*things_type/:id', to: 'administrated_things#show'
        put    'administrated/*things_type/:id', to: 'administrated_things#update'
        patch  'administrated/*things_type/:id', to: 'administrated_things#update'
        delete 'administrated/*things_type/:id', to: 'administrated_things#destroy'          
      end
    end
  end

end
```

So, when I do `rake routes`, I get:

```
  GET    /api/v0/people/:person_id/administrated/*things_type(.:format)                   api/v0/administrated_things#index {:format=>"json"}
  POST   /api/v0/people/:person_id/administrated/*things_type(.:format)                   api/v0/administrated_things#create {:format=>"json"}
  GET    /api/v0/people/:person_id/administrated/*things_type/:id(.:format)               api/v0/administrated_things#show {:format=>"json"}
  PUT    /api/v0/people/:person_id/administrated/*things_type/:id(.:format)               api/v0/administrated_things#update {:format=>"json"}
  PATCH  /api/v0/people/:person_id/administrated/*things_type/:id(.:format)               api/v0/administrated_things#update {:format=>"json"}
  DELETE /api/v0/people/:person_id/administrated/*things_type/:id(.:format)               api/v0/administrated_things#destroy {:format=>"json"}
```

This works great. It routes to my `AdministratedThingsContoller` and in params, I get `person_id` and `things_type`. And I use `things_type` (doing something like `params[:things_type].singularize.camelize.constantize`) to interact as appropriate with `Organization` and `Program`. AWESOME!

And in my client app, I can do something like:

```
  get https://www.my_api.com/api/v0/people/1/administrated/organizations
```

and get back a JSON representation of all the organizations that person with id = 1 administrates.

So, my question: Is there a simpler way (rather than crafting all the routes by hand as I'm doing now) of generating these routes using a nested resource along with a wildcard?

I've read the Rails guide on Routing from the Outside In. Tried a bunch of variations with no luck. I'm okay leaving the routes hand crafted, but feel like I'm lacking the understanding of how to be a routes Boss and just sort of hamfisting my way through this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably err on the side of a little duplication and add separate controllers for each "thing", even if they do pretty much the same thing. You can abstract any important duplicated logic out into a separate ruby class, or inherit some shared logic from an `AdministeredController`:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v0 do
    resources :people do
      namespace :administered do
        resources :organizations
        resources :programs
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When you use `constantize`, it's important to be careful you're not accepting arbitrary user input, as they could input any class name into the url:

```
get https://www.my_api.com/api/v0/people/1/administrated/objects
get https://www.my_api.com/api/v0/people/1/administrated/users
get https://www.my_api.com/api/v0/people/1/administrated/arrays
```

In all likelihood, it'll just cause a weird harmless error somewhere, but they might also get lucky and gain access to something they shouldn't be able to see, or cause some data corruption.